# How to console text in an element using Cypress?

Tags: javascript, testing, cypress

I am using Cypress for testing. I want to make sure that certain data is collected when on the page, but that does not show in the html. I have added hidden html elements for this purpose, which looks like this:

```
<div class="hidden">
    <p id="c.campaign">3005</p>
</div>
```

Now I want to use my Cypress test to make sure that there is a campaign saved to the page. This is what I have so far:

```
cy.get('#c.campaign').should('not.be.visible').invoke('text').then((text) => {
    cy.log(text)
})
```

The should not be visible is necessary as the element it hidden and does not find it otherwise. It should be logging **3005** but nothing is appearing. 
[image: failed test]

Answer (score 2):

Turns out the problem was having my classes named with a '.'. I believe that was breaking the jquery text function. I changed my classes to this format

```
<p id="test-campaign">3005</p>
```

and this code now works.

```
  cy.get('#test-campaign')
    .should('not.be.visible')
    .invoke('text').then((text) => {
      campaign = text
      cy.log('campaign',  text)
    })
```

Comment: you can backslash the periods - that's another solution to that issue.

Comment: Those are not class-, but id-selectors (I guess selectors is what you refer to as classes). id selectors are supposed to be unique across the whole DOM (html page), unlike reusable classes. When you query like "#c.campaign" it tells JQuery (which Cypress uses under the hood) to look for an element with id "c" and a class "campaign". id selectors are referenced by the hash in front of them and class-selectors by the period. If you left a space between those selectors ('#c .campaign'), JQuery would find an element with class campaign inside a parent with id c. TLDR: don't use reserved symbols.